# Demonstrate the difference in performance of function returning value and function not returning any value both function with identical codes

Tags: objective-c, function

1. As a curiosity i held one experiment in objective C:
2. My assumtion before starting the experiment was function returning value should take more time (Nanoseconds) than function with no returns.
3. Two functions having same number and same codes but one returning value and another not returning the value were written.

   ```
       -(void)methodNotReturningTheValue
   {
        //Some Codes  + @""
   }

   -(NSString*)methodReturningTheValue
   {
      //Some Codes 
       return @"";    
   }
   ```
4. The time is shown in nano second before and after calling the function. Below are the results:
   Example:

Time Before Calling methodNotReturningTheValue: 1411033150.946451

Time Before Calling methodReturningTheValue: 1411033150.946978

Difference in Time (Before and after) for methodReturningTheValue:0.000527

Time Before Calling methodReturningTheValue: 1411033150.947947

Time Before Calling methodReturningTheValue: 1411033150.948464

Difference in Time (Before and after) for methodReturningTheValue: 0.000517

4. The results are not consisted. Sometime time consume by methodreturningvalue is greater and sometime methodNotReturning value is greater.  May be the fluctuation in working of [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]; is not allowing the experiment to calculate the time consumed by function returning and not returning values.
5. am i sounding irrelative or any direction or solution to solve this curiosity:
   My Query: How to demonstrate performance difference between function returning value and function with out any return (Void) in any language?

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A value returned from a method is stored in a register (at least under ARM and <= 16-bytes; see the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442278/question-about-objective-c-calling-convention-and-argument-passing-on-arm)) and so that difference between the methods is irrelevant when a reference is returned.

A method returning a `struct` on the other hand will be more relevant, given the `struct` must be copied back to the caller.